# Creating a Style Sheet Based on User Inputs With Node.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm looking for a way to create a custom user style sheet, based off of user inputs, using user inputs.  Basically, users select different options, such as background colors etc., and then the app will create a style sheet based off their inputs.  Their inputs are done through HTML inputs tied to some jQuery functions.  The style sheets will be saved in a user database, that they can potentially view/download.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: There are some libraries that create on the fly css for you, like [this](https://github.com/reworkcss/css) one.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to put this to use?

Comment: I don't know your knowledge of NodeJs, but if you don't know how to create a nodejs server or import modules into your program I would suggest to first read some tutorials about that before digging into this! You could consider using [Express](http://expressjs.com/)!!

Comment: I know the basics - such as what you mentioned.  I just meant what exactly could I use this module for?  Sorry, a bit tired at the moment.

Comment: Well, you could store specific css settings in the DB, then when the css is requested, you can dynamically generate the css (using that library I mentioned before) and send it to the browser (which also means you don't need to write it to a file). For performance reasons (if any) you can write the generated css to file or keep it in memory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Save css in database
2. Create actually file and while viewing parse it to display style classes.

Go through step below:

Step one: Answer your question in yes or no

1. Is your application is for web designers?
2. Is your application has one feature of theme?
3. Is there is frequent changes in css styling?
4. Is this feature for end user?

Step two: Find out your answer with keeping user in mind.

Step three: Take decision

If question 1 and 3 is yes then save it is in database and when web designer publish changes make style sheet, and fetch from DB for viewing.

If question 2 and 4 is yes then make style sheet, use that when you going to apply that sheet and parse for viewing.

Comment: This is definitely a great first step - I haven't taken on a task like this before so I wasn't sure where to start.  Do you happen to know of any resources that could help me with the actual coding?

Comment: You can use key value pair to store and use suitable database (e.g. mongo) or you can use any parsing module of node with fs module.